# Distribution limit of $\sum_{k=1}^n \cos kx$

Tags: distribution-theory

How can we find the limit of $\sum_{k=1}^n \cos kx$ as $n\to\infty$ in the distributional sense?

I have no idea but the following direct computation:

$$\langle \sum_{k=1}^n \cos kx,\phi \rangle
=\int_{\Bbb R}\sum_{k=1}^n \cos kx \ \phi(x) \ dx
=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\Bbb R} \cos kx \ \phi(x) \ dx \\
=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\Bbb R} \cos y\frac{1}{k} \ \phi(\frac{y}{k}) \ dy
=\int_{\Bbb R} \sum_{\nu=1}^m \frac{1}{k} \ \phi(\frac{y}{k})\cos y \ dy $$

for any test function $\phi$.

Then what is the limit?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The [Dirac comb distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) of period $T$ is given by
$$ \text{III}_T(t) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(t-kT) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{2\pi i k t/T} $$

Comment: (this is the Fourier series theorem in the language of distributions)

Comment: @reuns If I am not mistaken, to be precise, it is the Poisson summation formula.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski Both are [the same](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Poisson_Summation_Formula). To be precise it says $\lim_{n \to \infty} D_n =  \delta$ as  distributions on the circle, where $D_n(x)= \sum_{m=-n}^n e^{2i \pi  m x}$ is the Dirichlet kernel

Comment: @reuns It may depend from the references but for me, the fundamental theorem of Fourier series for distributions is the following: For each $T \in \mathscr{D }_{\gamma-periodic}'( \mathbb{R})$, there exists a sequence $(a_n)_n$ of (at most) polynomial growth such that $T= \sum a_k e^{\frac{ik 2 \pi}{\gamma}}$. Furthermore, if $(a_n)_n$ is any sequence of polynomial growth, the series $\sum a_k e^{\frac{ik 2 \pi}{\gamma}}$ converges in $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski Yes, and convolution is well-defined for distributions on the circle $S^1$, so $D_n \to \delta$ is the same as $\forall T \in D'(S^1), T \ast D_n \to T$.

Comment: @reuns I see, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski To make this rigorous, I would try something like that : if $T,S \in (C^\infty(S^1))'$ and $\phi \in C^\infty(S^1)$ then $T \ast \phi \in C^\infty(S^1)$ so that $S \ast (T \ast \phi) \in C^\infty(S^1)$ and hence the convolution of distributions $S \ast T \in (C^\infty(S^1))'$ is well-defined. More generally, the circle $S^1$ is compact, and convolution of distributions with compact support is well-defined.

Comment: @reuns But this needs to be transfered to $ \mathbbR$ instead of $S^1$. I guess periodization needs to come into play one way or another.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski Why that ? If $T \in D'(\mathbb{R})$ is a $1$-periodic distribution and $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ then $\langle T,\phi \rangle = \langle \tilde{T}, \tilde{\phi} \rangle$ where $\tilde{\phi}(x) = \sum_n \phi(x+n) \in C^\infty(S^1)$ and $\tilde{T}$ is a distribution on the circle. In other words periodic distributions and distributions on the circle are the same thing.